# Using the sinc function for interpolation

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, interpolation, coordinate-transformation

For a university assignment, I have to interpolate some points that I had previously sampled from a wave. It works as long as I interpolate them with the `interp1` function.

My teacher wants us to interpolate it using the `sinc` function, so I googled it and the mathworks documentation says I should do this:

```
rng default

t = 1:10;
x = randn(size(t))';
ts = linspace(-5,15,600);
[Ts,T] = ndgrid(ts,t);
y = sinc(Ts - T)*x;

plot(t,x,'o',ts,y)
xlabel Time, ylabel Signal
legend('Sampled','Interpolated','Location','SouthWest')
legend boxoff
```

It works, but since I have to interpolate points that are in a reduced domain I modified the code to try and interpolate points that are in the range from `0` to `1`:

```
rng shuffle

t = 0:0.1:1;
x = randn(size(t))';
ts = linspace(-1,2,600);
[Ts,T] = ndgrid(ts,t);
y = sinc(Ts - T)*x;

plot(t,x,'o',ts,y)
xlabel Time, ylabel Signal
legend('Sampled','Interpolated','Location','SouthWest')
legend boxoff
```

And it just doesn't work properly, I get this from the above:

[image: Figure]

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong, or if `sinc` only works in "big" domains?

Comment: What interpolation algorithm do you want to implement/use? What does the result look like in the "big" domain?

Answer (score 5):

You should also scale your sinc function in the time direction to fit your data:

```
dt = 0.1;
y = sinc((Ts - T)/dt)*x;
```

**Explanation**

Because you want to interpolate between your data point, you should be sure that the interpolation function (`f`) of the other data points is zero at the current data point:

```
f(k*dt) = 0    for all integers k != 0
```

It is known that

```
sinc(k) = 0    for all integers k != 0
```

Therefore your interpolation function should be

```
f(t) = sinc(t/dt);
```